# PHP CodeIgniter and JQuery AJAX append table row using jquery and insert all table data to database

Tags: mysql, ajax, codeigniter, insert

PHP CodeIgniter and JQuery AJAX append table row using jquery and insert all table data to database
insert 'r' in my sql i need help

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's more info here as well. [Codeigniter - Append rows in view then add those rows to database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968370/codeigniter-append-rows-in-view-then-add-those-rows-to-database-table)

Make sure to include "this->db->insert_batch" in your model file. Also in your "input type=" code in your view be sure to have "name="yournamefield[]".